# Aiohttp not performing any requests

Tags: python, asynchronous, aiohttp

First of all heres the code:

```
import random
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import csv

headers =[]
def extractsites(file):
    sites = []
    readfile = open(file, "r")
    reader = csv.reader(readfile, delimiter=",")
    raw = list(reader)
    for a in raw:
        sites.append((a[1]))
    return sites

async def bound_fetch(sem, url):
    async with sem:
        print("doing request for "+ url)
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                responseheader = await response.headers
                print(headers)


async def run():
    urls = extractsites("cisco-umbrella.csv")
    tasks = []
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(100)
    for i in urls:
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem, "http://"+i))
        tasks.append(task)
    headers = await asyncio.wait(*tasks)
    print(headers)


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(run())
    loop.run_until_complete(future)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As per my last question I'm following this blog post:
https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html

I tried to adapt my code as close as possible to the example implementation but this code is still not making any requests and printing the headers in `bound_headers` as I wish.

Can somebody spot whats wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`response.headers`](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse.headers) is a regular property, no need to put await before the call

[`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) on other hand accepts a list of futures and returns `(done, pending)` pair.
Looks like you should replace `await wait()` call with `await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` ([gather doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather))

Comment: makes sense, can you explain in what scenario i should use `wait()` instead of `gather()` ?

Comment: When you need collecting result with relative small timeout, processing ready answers and wait again for unprocessed yet results.